# Cannot create an HTTP scratch file for an API gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, httprequest

I am new to this IntelliJ IDE and I happen to come across creating a HTTP scratch file to test a project's APIs. But in my IntelliJ, the file type for HTTP Request is not under the list when creating a scratch file.

[screenshot of scratch file types available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFHXx.png)

This is my IntelliJ version:

[IntelliJ Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SJoQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must choose File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Http Editor Client . This must be enabled.

Then you will see .rest for http Request.